# Fitting data in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, mathematical-optimization, dataset

Consider the 'm' matrix: Link to 'matrix.dat':  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1COdMCCBKq85vMDj6Jrb2qqoUlE9eTk6w?usp=sharing

```
m = Import["matrix.dat"];
```

[image]

I would like to fit the surface to this data now and then subtract it from the input matrix:

```
{DIM1, DIM2} = Dimensions@m;
NEWDATA = Outer[{#1, #2, m[[#1, #2]]} &, Range[DIM1], Range[DIM2]];
NEWDATA2 = Flatten[NEWDATA, 1];
FIT = FindFit[NEWDATA2, a x^2 + b y + c, {a, b, c}, {x, y}];
FIT1 = (Evaluate[a (#1)^2 + b #2 + c /. FIT]) &;
DATAdetr = Table[FIT1[i, j], {i, 1, DIM1}, {j, 1, DIM2}];
AfterDetr = m - DATAdetr;
```

```
ListPlot3D[AfterDetr, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], MeshStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 600]
```

The problem is that data is detrended also for zeros elements.
How to make only non-zero data considered?

I have code in Matlab but I don't know if it works properly:

```
load matrix.dat

%%% cumsum the data
matrix_T = matrix';
[a,b] = find(matrix_T > 0); 

ind = sub2ind(size(matrix_T),a,b);
s = length(ind); % box size;

matrix_T_cum = zeros(size(matrix_T,1),size(matrix_T,2));

matrix_T_cum (ind) = cumsum(matrix_T(ind));

matrix_cum = matrix_T_cum';

%%%  fitting the model
[X,Y]=ndgrid(1:size(matrix_cum,1),1:size(matrix_cum,2));

fit_model=fit([X(:),Y(:)], matrix_cum(:),'poly55', 'Exclude', matrix_cum(:) == 0);
plot(fit_model, [X(:),Y(:)], matrix_cum(:), 'Exclude', matrix_cum(:) == 0) %only data in the box are considered

vector_matrix_cum_fitted =fit_model([X(:),Y(:)]);
matrix_cum_fitted = reshape(vector_matrix_cum_fitted ,size(matrix_cum,1), size(matrix_cum,2)); 
matrix_cum_detrend = matrix_cum - matrix_cum_fitted;
plot3(X(:),Y(:), matrix_cum_detrend(:))
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `Select` function to select just the non-zero elements?  And do you need that before or after the "detrending" or both?

Comment: It would be best to fit without zeros (i.e. not to include them when you fiting) .

Comment: What happened when you used `Select`?

Comment: I don't know how to fit the surface to the data when I remove the zeros from the matrix 'm'.

Comment: I think maybe we're talking in circles. If you use `Select` you can get rid of the zeros and then just do the fitting you did before.

Comment: `NEWDATA3 = Select[NEWDATA2, #[[3]] != 0 &]`

Comment: See update ....

Comment: Getting NEWDATA2 can be written `Flatten[MapIndexed[Flatten@{#2, #1} &, m, {2}], 1]`

Comment: I'm still not following the logic of what you want to do.  From `I would like to fit the surface to this data now and then subtract it from the input matrix" and statements about zeros (using the jargon "detrended for the zeros" doesn't help), you want to fit the original data (without the zeros), then find the residuals, and then perform another fit on the residuals.  The last part doesn't make sense at least until you take a look at the residuals to see where the original function might be inadequate.  Then that might suggest an improvement to the original model.

Comment: The question is. How to fit a surface to only non-zero data?

Answer (score 1):

I think @JimB answered your question, but I'll work it through.

```
m = Import["matrix.dat"];
MatrixPlot@m
```

[image]

```
NEWDATA2 = Flatten[MapIndexed[Flatten@{#2, #1} &, m, {2}], 1];
ND3      = Select[NEWDATA2, #[[3]] != 0 &];
```

Plotting just the nonzero parts

```
ListPlot3D[ND3]
```

[image]

Get the indices of the nonzero parts

```
indices = ND3[[All, {1, 2}]];
```

Get your rules for the fit

```
FIT = FindFit[ND3, a x^2 + b y + c, {a, b, c}, {x, y}]

(*  {a -> 0.0541017, b -> 2.68527, c -> -86.772}  *)
```

Make a function fit, slightly different form

```
fcn[{x_, y_}] := (Evaluate[a x^2 + b y + c /. FIT]);
```

Get your detrended data

```
dtd = Map[Flatten@{#, fcn[#]} &, indices];

ListPlot3D[{ND3, dtd}]
```

[image]

To get the detrended data `dtd` back to a matrix, we can use a `SparseArray` as an intermediary. Create the rules for the sparse array.

```
sar = Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} -> #[[3]] &, dtd];
sar[[1]]
(*   {1, 42} -> 26.0632   *)

sa = SparseArray[sar]
```

[image]

And subtract this from the original matrix

```
MatrixPlot[m - sa]
```

[image]